# Disabling and enabling constraints during runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, constraints, optaplanner

I've set the constaints like this:-

```
ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig scoreDirectorFactoryConfig = new ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig();         scoreDirectorFactoryConfig.setConstraintProviderClass(VehicleRoutingConstraintProvider.class);
```

I couldn't find out anything related to enabling and/or disabling constraints in optaplanner.

So, I wanted to know if there's a way to enable and disable the constraints after or before setting the constraint provider class.

My question is:

**Can we enable and/or disable constraint during runtime in optaplanner based on a condition?**

Answer (score 1):

You can disable constraints by using a `@ConstraintConfiguration` class and set the `@ConstraintWeight` field corresponding to the disabled constraint to the zero score (see https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/score-calculation/score-calculation.html#constraintConfiguration for full details).

Planning Solution Class:

```
@PlanningSolution
public class ConferenceSolution {
    
    @ConstraintConfigurationProvider
    private ConferenceConstraintConfiguration constraintConfiguration;
    
    // ...
}
```

ConstraintConfiguration:

```
@ConstraintConfiguration(constraintPackage = "...conferencescheduling.score")
public class ConferenceConstraintConfiguration {

    @ConstraintWeight("Speaker conflict")
    private HardMediumSoftScore speakerConflict = HardMediumSoftScore.ofHard(10);

    @ConstraintWeight("Theme track conflict")
    private HardMediumSoftScore themeTrackConflict = HardMediumSoftScore.ofSoft(10);
    @ConstraintWeight("Content conflict")
    private HardMediumSoftScore contentConflict = HardMediumSoftScore.ofSoft(100);

    // ...
}
```

Disabling constraints

```
ConferenceConstraintConfiguration constraintConfig = new ConferenceConstraintConfiguration();
constraintConfig.contentConflict = HardMediumSoftScore.ZERO;
```

Comment: I tried working following the above way, but even if I use constraintweight and change the score to zero, it's considering the constraint and changing the starttime. I want the constraint to disable when this condition is true:- 'if(!routingProblem.getConstraintNames().contains("updateStartTimeConstraint")) {
            ConferenceConstraintConfiguration constraintConfig = new ConferenceConstraintConfiguration();
            constraintConfig.setUpdateStartTime(BendableLongScore.zero(2,1));
            solution.setConstraintConfiguration(constraintConfig);
        }`

Comment: Constraints should not change the problem/solution during evaluation; if you need to update some fields during solving, use shadow variables instead: (https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/shadow-variable/shadow-variable.html). OptaPlanner may choose a move that updates the start time if it does not decrease the score. So if you don't want moves that update the start time to be generated in certain conditions, you need to generate the moves yourself (https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html).